# How to make online help for PHP web application?

Tags: php

I got an PHP/JS web application and my boss wants me to add an online help in it. Idea is that after click on some "button" it will show some new window with help. There should be some indexing and searching... Simply something like Windows help... Is there any FREE software which allows me to do this? I have absolutely no experience with this, so I don´t know what to download, what is the best and how to implement it. Any tips appreciated ;)

Comment: i don't think there is something like that that you can download and then install. you must do it yourself using javascript / ajax

Comment: You can have a look at the way wordpress did their contextual help

Comment: For such purpose I suggest you is to create a `demo video` showing tutorial of site or `demo site` with some data sample data.

Comment: For example I´d like something like this: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#HomePage/CustomDocument9453 .... This can also be done using PHP/JS only?

Comment: Rikesh Shah: Unfortunately I think that would be way too much complicated, the app is rather complex and such video would be too long or there would have to be many of those videos, for which I wouldn´t have enough space... FoxMaSk: Where can I take a look at that? I found something about WP, but it seems I´d have to download it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use HelpNDoc!

HelpNDoc outputs in many formats including CHM (Which is what makes Windows help).

Formats:

HTML
Microsoft Word
PDF
ePub
CHM

Free Version is available but does add a footer advert for HelpNDoc.

http://www.helpndoc.com

Edit: And there's indexing and searching built in